# Unsupported action method signature. Must return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this error whenever I'm running simulator on iOS 13+. Everything works for iOS 12 and below so I'm not sure what to do here. Is there anything I can change/edit on my end to make `react-native-music-control` work for iOS 13?

`Exception 'Unsupported action method signature. Must return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus or take a completion handler as the second argument.' was thrown while invoking enableControl on target MusicControlManager with params ( pause, 1, { } )`

Comment: Do what the error message tells you. I know nothing about react but here’s a working example in Swift: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p644remote/ch27p912ducking/ViewController.swift Note how my handlers all return a status.

Answer (score 5):

This `react-native-music-control` probably hasn't updated its iOS MediaPlayer methods.
One common method is MediaPlayer's `addTarget`. Starting iOS 13, this method must return a `MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus`. It used to return nothing in previous iOS versions.

For example, if you have a `play` method that gets called when the Play button is tapped:

```
- (void) play { 
/* start playing */
}
```

You are probably registering this `play` to be called when the Media Player's `play` command is trigged:

```
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(play)];
```

**Then, all you need is to simply change your `play` method to return a `MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus` like this:**

```
- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) play
{
    // if successfully played
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;

    // else if there's an issue
    // return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusCommandFailed;
}
```

This is in Objective-C. Changing the return value in Swift will be simple too.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommand/1622895-addtarget?language=objc

Comment: Yo thanks, I'm using the same plugin in my Cordova project and I started having the same problem ... Since the plugin is not being maintained for more than 2 years I had to do it on my own, and your explanation really saved me ,

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

So this plugin is not being maintained anymore I don't know why, so for those using this plugin the solution is really Simple, based on what @CSawy. I was able to fix it.

### 1 -  Change the method signature to `MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus`

All the methods that interact with the control are defined as void so change them to MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus. They are defined in the file `MusicControls` and I guess you would find it in your plugins folder. For me it was in `myProject/plugins/MusiControls.h`

These are the methods that require the change

- playEvent
- pauseEvent
- nextTrackEvent
- prevTrackEvent
- skipForwardEvent
- skipBackwardEvent

After changing all the methods signature u should have

`(MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) playEvent:(MPRemoteCommandEvent *) event;`

`(MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) pauseEvent:(MPRemoteCommandEvent *) event;`

`(MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) nextTrackEvent:(MPRemoteCommandEvent *) event;`

`(MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) prevTrackEvent:(MPRemoteCommandEvent *) event;`

`(MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) skipForwardEvent: (MPSkipIntervalCommandEvent *) event;`

`(MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) skipBackwardEvent: (MPSkipIntervalCommandEvent *) event;`

### `2-Add return to the implementations`

Now you should change the implementation of these methods otherwise your app would still be crushing.

Simply open the file `MusicControls.m`. If you are using Xcode it will highlight the methods for you ... If it's no highlighted then just search for them
For all these functions you will need to add a return ;

For your `play event` do:

```swift
-(MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) playEvent:(MPRemoteCommandEvent *)event {
    NSString * action = @"music-controls-play";
    NSString * jsonAction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"message\":\"%@\"}", action];
    CDVPluginResult * pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:jsonAction];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:[self latestEventCallbackId]];
    
  return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}
```

Do this for all the methods and I hope it works.